# onClick event handling on a Styled-component (DIV)

Tags: html, reactjs, onclick, event-handling, styled-components

I would like to handle an onClick event on a DIV (in REACT JS) which is a styled-component actually. But this not works at all.

Here is the pseudo code of my build-up:

```
<Styled_DIV onClick={() => props.method(props.arg)}>
  <AnotherElement/>
  ...
</Styled_DIV>
```

My workaround which works properly:

```
<div onClick={() => props.method(props.arg)}>
 <Styled_DIV}>
   <AnotherElement/>
   ...
 </Styled_DIV>
</div>
```

So, my question is: what's the official / best way to handle an onClick event on a styled-component div without wrapper div?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can attach the event handlers directly without wrapper div.

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Wrapper from "./Wrapper";

const App = () => <Wrapper onClick={() => alert("Hello")}>Hello</Wrapper>;

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Wrapper.js:

```
import styled from "styled-components";

export default styled.button`
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  color: palevioletred;
`;
```

Code Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-d731y?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

You also have other options like 
typestyle https://github.com/typestyle/typestyle, 
Styletron https://github.com/styletron/styletron and others as well which can be used with react.

Comment: Thanks for your great help. :) Based on this guide, I created a sandbox project and with its help I've found what was the problem in my other project. There was a 'z-index' attribute in CSS settings of DIV which had a minus value therefore the div didn't triggered because it was the last in layer hierarchy behind the body. Well, your answer is right, so I'm gonna set it to the right answer. Thanks your help again. :)

Answer (score -2):

because you don't create the Styled_DIV component that'll render an  tag

just add this code

const Styled_DIV = styled.div``

Comment: Sorry, I was misunderstandable. Of course, I declared a styled.div`` before, I just missed to mentioned it because I thought it is obvious. Sorry, my fault.