# How to pass onclick method to child component from parent using react, typescript, and styled-component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I want to pass the onclick method from child to parent using react and typescript.

**what I am trying do?**

I have a parent component which renders child component and is like below,

```
function Parent() {
    const [isDialogOpen, setisDialogOpen] = useState('');
    const set =() => {
        setisDialogOpen(!isDialogOpen);
    }

    return (
        <Child size={16} fontSize={12}/>
    );
}

interface Props {
    size?: number;
    fontSize?: number;
}

const Child = styled.div<Props>`
    font-size: ${p => (p.fontSize ? p.fontSize + 'px' : '8px')};
    size: ${p => (p.fontSize ? p.fontSize + 'px' : '12px')}
`;

 export default Child;
```

Now, how can I add onClick method to the Child component such that it sets the isDialogOpen state?

**what I tried?**

I was trying to do something like below,

```
function Parent() {
    const [isDialogOpen, setisDialogOpen] = useState('');
    const setDialog =() => {
        setisDialogOpen(!isDialogOpen);
    }

    return (
        <Child onClick={setDialog} size={16} fontSize={12}/>
    );
}

interface Props {
    onClick?: () => void;
    size?: number;
    fontSize?: number;
}

const Child = styled.div<Props>`
    font-size: ${p => (p.fontSize ? p.fontSize + 'px' : '8px')};
    size: ${p => (p.fontSize ? p.fontSize + 'px' : '12px')}
`;

 export default Child;
```

But how can I add the onClick method to div near this line?

```
const Child = styled.div<Props>`
    font-size: ${p => (p.fontSize ? p.fontSize + 'px' : '8px')};
    size: ${p => (p.fontSize ? p.fontSize + 'px' : '12px')}
`;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap Child component with a function.

```
const StyledChild = styled.div<Props>`
    font-size: ${p => (p.fontSize ? p.fontSize + 'px' : '8px')};
    size: ${p => (p.fontSize ? p.fontSize + 'px' : '12px')}
`;

const Child = ({fontSize, size, onClick}: Props) => {
  return (
     <StyledChild onClick={onClick} fontSize={fontSize} size={size} />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the `Child` with a component and give it's wrapper an `onClick` event listener

check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59396964/onclick-event-handling-on-a-styled-component-div)